# Jquery - append after remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, keypress

after press key "," i append new input, when i use backspace last input is removed, but after delete all inputs  when i press again  "," code return all inputs, not one. how fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/3r79hyoL/

```
$(".multipleField").keyup(function(e) {
var key = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
if (key == 110 || key == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(value.replace(",", ""));
    $(this).first().clone().appendTo(".multipleFields").focus().val("");
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('makeBorder');
    replaceAndCopy();

}

if (key == 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(".multipleFields").last().val() == "" && $(".multipleField").length > 1) {
        $(".multipleField").last().remove();
        $(".multipleField").last().focus();
    }
}
});

function replaceAndCopy() {
$(".multipleField").keyup(function(e) {
    var key = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if (key == 110 || key == 188) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(value.replace(",", ""));
        $(this).clone().appendTo(".multipleFields").focus().val("");

        $(this).addClass('makeBorder');

        replaceAndCopy();

    }

    if (key == 8) {
        if ($(".multipleFields").last().val() == "" && 
$(".multipleField").length != 1) {
            $(".multipleField:last").remove();
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".multipleField").last().focus();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attaching new event listeners to every input. So when you go back to an input that is not the last one the event is fired more than one time.

```
function replaceAndCopy() {
// Add new event listener to all inputs, instead of the last
// $(".multipleField").keyup(function(e) {
// Change to
$(".multipleField").last().keyup(function(e) {
    var key = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if (key == 110 || key == 188) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(value.replace(",", ""));
        $(this).clone().appendTo(".multipleFields").focus().val("");

        $(this).addClass('makeBorder');

        replaceAndCopy();

    }

    if (key == 8) {
        if ($(".multipleFields").last().val() == "" && $(".multipleField").length != 1) {
            $(".multipleField:last").remove();
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".multipleField").last().focus();
        }
    }
});
```